# how to split the number of days in monthwise between two month

Tags: sql-server

hi i want to find the total days of two month and split the days for month wise..for example...
26-02-2013 to 3-3-2013
here for the february month it shows 2days leave but march month i wont display the total leave..this is my query..can anyone correct my query..it shows only febraury days only,,march days is not shown here..

```
SELECT  month(fdate) as Month_Number
        , datename(month, fdate) as Month
        , case when month(fdate) <> month(tdate) then 
            datediff(day, fdate, DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(fdate) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(fdate), -1)) 
          else 
            datediff(day, fdate, tdate) 
          end as Leaves 
from    test 
where   empid like '112'
```

Comment: pls could you elaborate a bit further and perhaps give a sample of what the data looks like and the result you are expecting.

Comment: Can you post some test data and DML statements together with expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will display the number of days for each month:

```
SELECT  *
        , DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.fdate) + 1, 0)) Last_In_Month_Of_Beginning
        , DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, t.tdate), 0) First_In_Month_Of_End
INTO    #temp1
FROM    test t
WHERE   empid LIKE '112'

SELECT  number Month_Number
        , CASE 
            WHEN MONTH(fdate) = MONTH(tdate) THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, fdate, tdate) - 1
            WHEN MONTH(Last_In_Month_Of_Beginning) = number THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, fdate, Last_In_Month_Of_Beginning)
            WHEN MONTH(First_In_Month_Of_End) = number THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, First_In_Month_Of_End, tdate)
          END Leave
INTO    #temp2
FROM    #temp1 a
JOIN    master..spt_values v ON
        v.type = 'P'
AND     v.number BETWEEN MONTH(a.Last_In_Month_Of_Beginning) AND MONTH(a.First_In_Month_Of_End)

SELECT  Month_Number
        , SUM(Leave) Leaves
FROM    #temp2
GROUP BY Month_Number
```

Here is an **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab6b4/12/1)**